# Why angularjs's constant not working with factory

Tags: angularjs

I have constant mainApp.constant('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:63760') , i need to use it as default base url for all of my factory. when I inject it to a controller, it's working perfectly, but not working with factory(when factory called by the controller) giving an undefined error. please see my below codes.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]);

mainApp.constant('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:63760');
```

**factory**

```
mainApp.factory('StudentServices', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope, baseUrl) {
    return {
        GetStudentProfileByPIN: function (param) {
            alert(baseUrl);
            return $http({
                url: baseUrl + '/Api/ApiProfile/GetStudentProfile/' + param,
                method: 'POST',
                async: false
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**controller**

```
    mainApp.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $window, StudentServices) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.login = function () {
        StudentServices.GetStudentProfileByPIN($scope.PIN).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.Student != null) {
                $window.localStorage.setItem('Student', angular.toJson(response.data));
                $window.location.href = "/Profile/#/home";
            }
            else {
                alert(response.data.Message);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing **`'baseUrl',`**You should have it as,

```
mainApp.factory('StudentServices', ['$http', '$rootScope','baseUrl', function ($http, $rootScope, baseUrl) {
```

Answer (score 1):

inject the string `baseUrl` too

```
mainApp.factory('StudentServices', ['$http', '$rootScope','baseUrl' function ($http, $rootScope, baseUrl)
```